# Need to implement the Rollback in release pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I made one release pipeline with one stage for deployment and second stage of Selenium test case as per the image.

[image]

Please tell me how can i revert the deployment when Selenium test case got failed. Means when my second stage fails my first task also should be reverted. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the previous successful deployment if something fails. Will that solve your case?

Below you can see an example of a post deployment condition and a rerun of the last successful release.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell me how can i revert the deployment when Selenium test case got failed.

The most effective way is that you could manually choose the previous record of successful release, then you could use the **`"Redeploy"`** option to deploy the stage (dev stage) again.

[image: Re-Deploy]

**Additional info:**

I set the "**Auto-redeploy trigger**" (Deployment to this stage fails) in Stage 2. When the stage 2 is failed, it only re-deploys the previous successful Stage 2. The Stage 1 will not roll back.

[image]

Hope this helps.